# how to get image to show up to the left of panel (both in same row)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why are the arrow images going into the panel? I put the arrow images into their own column but they are intersecting the panel.
When I give the panel its own column then the images do not intersect it, but the gap between the images and the panel is too large. How do I get the arrow images to show up to the left of the of panel, in the same row?

```
<div class="row comment" id="1">
            <div  class="col-xs-1">
                    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-up-b-128.png" name="up" class="img-responsive resize">
                    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png" name="down" class="img-responsive resize">
            </div>
            <div >
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        user
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        text
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                                <li><a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0)">reply</a></li>
                                <li><a class="expand" href="javascript:void(0)"> expand</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="delete" href="javascript:void(0)"> delete</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="edit" href="javascript:void(0)"> edit</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.comment{
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.resize{
    width:40px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9ut9agz/1/).
Here is how i want it to look :[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7o9ue8a/1/)
I cannot use this solution because I need the whole row to have the comment css rule that gives it a left margin of 50px since I will have many child comments inside of child comments.

Comment: How is this supposed to look?

Comment: how we now what is the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the arrows in grid 1 and rest of the panel in remaining grids.
This will have arrows and panels in the same row.

```css
.comment{
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.resize{
    width:40px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row comment" id="1">
            <div  class="col-xs-1 arrows-block">
                    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-up-b-128.png" name="up" class="img-responsive resize">
                    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png" name="down" class="img-responsive resize">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-11" >
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        user
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        text
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                                <li><a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0)">reply</a></li>
                                <li><a class="expand" href="javascript:void(0)"> expand</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="delete" href="javascript:void(0)"> delete</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="edit" href="javascript:void(0)"> edit</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```